# Exclusion in IIS HTTP Redirect

Tags: http, redirect

We want to redirect all users to a particular aspx or html page during downtime of the site during deployment.

But we want few members from development team would be able to see the site during this downtime. so if anything goes wrong in deployment they can resolve it immediately before making site live again.

Does IIS have such feature ? Can HTTP Redirect do such exclusion ?

~ VD.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an additional host header for your team to use and bind it to the site, e.g. if your site is company.com, add deploytest.company.com as an additional binding, then configure it in DNS or simply in the HOSTS file on your testing machines.  Then perform the redirect based on the requested URL using the IIS URL Rewrite engine.